# php if statement html option value

Tags: php, if-statement, html-select

Suppose you have the following html select statement

```
<select>
<option value="Newest">Newest</option>
<option value="Best Sellers">Best Sellers</option>
<option value="Alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to run a php if elseif statement that says,

```
if (option value = newest) {
// Run this
}
elseif ( option value = best sellers ) {
// Run this
}
```

etc.  But I don't know what to put inside the if elseif statement.  In other words instead of 'option value = newest' (which I know is incorrect), what can I put there so that if newest is selected it will execute the if statement, or if best sellers is selected it will execute the elseif statement?

Comment: read about HTML forms and PHP first..[http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give name to your select.

```
<select name="selectedValue">
<option value="Newest">Newest</option>
<option value="Best Sellers">Best Sellers</option>
<option value="Alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
</select>
```

in your PHP, you will do:

`$_POST['selectedValue'];`

if I were you, I would prefer a **switch-case** incase, there are more than 2 conditions.

Example:

```
switch($_POST['selectedValue']){
case 'Newest':
    // do Something for Newest
break;
case 'Best Sellers':
    // do Something for Best seller
break;
case 'Alphabetical':
    // do Something for Alphabetical
break;
default:
    // Something went wrong or form has been tampered.
}
```

Comment: What about if Selected drop-down options will be more than 100?

Comment: @Boyka I will recommend auto-fill with ajax.

Answer (score 6):

First put a name on your select:

```
<select name="demo">
<option value="Newest">Newest</option>
<option value="Best Sellers">Best Sellers</option>
<option value="Alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
</select>
```

Then

```
if ($_POST['demo'] === 'Newest') {
// Run this
}
elseif ( $_POST['demo'] === 'Best Sellers' ) {
// Run this
}
```

or

```
switch($_POST['demo']){
    case 'Newest' : 
        //some code;
        break;
    case 'Best Sellers':
        //some code;
        break;
    default:
        //some code if the post doesn't match anything
}
```

Comment: String indizes into arrays are case sensitive.

Comment: Fair point inattention mistake! (usually I don't put any uppercase characters or any space into the value to avoid this type of mistake)

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` should have a `name` attribute, e.g `<select name="sortorder">`. You could then say

```
if ($_REQUEST['sortorder'] == 'Newest') {
  // TODO sortorder 'Newest' was selected.
}
```

If you know whether the form data is comming in via HTTP GET or HTTP POST, you could use `$_GET['sortorder']` or `$_POST['sortorder']` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think the read-friendly version would be:

```
switch($option){
    case 'Newest':
        runNewestFunction();
    break;
    case 'Best Sellers':
        runBestSellersFunction();
    break;
    case 'Alphabetical':
        runAlphabeticalFunction();
    break;
    default:
        runValidationRequest();
}
```

also, please add the name attribute `<select name="option">`